# How to do cross browser/device Audio capture

Tags: html, cross-browser, audio-capture

I would like to clarify certain things with what I found and raise certain questions with things that I dont know,

Capturing cam/mic through browser could be done through getusermedia();

1. Is there anything for i devices? because getusermedia() doesn't seem to work in i devices
2. How could I trap actual audio from web browser application (eg. if I play an audio file and forward it 2mins, I would like to capture the actual audio stream from the html5 player so that I hold the actual audio data)

Comment: Insufficient information, the mothd for doing this varries by system and web browser.  

1)Caputure all system audio out (commercial soft available)
2)Caputure single program audio stream(significant hacking required to find allocated stream)
3)Browser provides plugin APIs that allow this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Flash, if you are not going to support mobile devices. One best solution is to use [wami-recorder](http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/).

From their website:

> #### The Problem
>
> As of this writing, most browsers still do not support WebRTC's getUserMedia(), which promises to give web developers microphone access via Javascript. This project achieves the next best thing for browsers that support Flash. Using the WAMI recorder, you can collect audio on your server without installing any proprietary media server software.
>
> #### The Solution
>
> The WAMI recorder uses a light-weight Flash app to ship audio from client to server via a standard HTTP POST. Apart from the security settings to allow microphone access, the entire interface can be constructed in HTML and Javascript.

Hope this helps.